# What is AC_COMPUTE_INT for CMake?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

For autotools there is a Macro called `AC_COMPUTE_INT`. It can be used to compute (detect) an integral compile time expression. How to do that in CMake?

A naive approach could be using `try_run` to output the number. However that breaks cross compilation and `AC_COMPUTE_INT` works with cross compilation by bisecting the number with compilation steps.

Edit:
The autotools `AC_COMPUTE_INT` works as follows:

- It has a short-cut when not cross compiling and just runs a program to make things faster.
- It repeatedly compiles a program containing (something similar to) `char somearray[boolean_compile_time_expression ? 1 : -1];` to learn the value of `boolean_compile_time_expression`.
- It first uses such an expression to check the sign of the integer expression being asked.
- Then it looks for a bound of the integer expression by repeatedly checking whether it is smaller than `2 * lastbound + 1` (positive case).
- Once it found an upper and lower bound, it does a binary search inside to get the actual value.
- It usually takes less than 50 compile tests. (It's a bit worse than testing for each bit individually in the worst case.) For many (in particular small) values, it takes much less tests.
- Since it doesn't use anything but the equivalent of `try_compile` (in the cross case), it is as portable as `try_compile`.
- `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF` uses `AC_COMPUTE_INT` and thus inherits its portability properties.

Answer (score 2):

After a few dumps of `gcc` intermediate compilation steps I've ended up with `-fdump-tree-original`. Which seems quite easy to parse and contains values of already evaluated expressions and `sizeof`.

Example C source:

```
#define FANCY_VALUE sizeof(int) * 10

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return FANCY_VALUE;
}
```

Result of `gcc -fdump-tree-original example.c`:

```
;; Function main (null)
;; enabled by -tree-original

{
    return 40;
}
return 0;
```

Sooo... One of probably non-portable and `gcc` specific ways might look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# AC_COMPUTE_INT function doing all the lifting
function(AC_COMPUTE_INT OUTPUT_VAR INPUT_EXP)
    set(C_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ac_computer.c)
    set(DUMP_FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ac_computer.dump)

    file(WRITE ${C_FILE}
        "int main(int argc, char **argv) { return ${INPUT_EXP};}"
    )

    execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -c -fdump-tree-original=${DUMP_FILE} ${C_FILE}
    )

    file(READ ${DUMP_FILE} AC_COMPUTER_DUMP)
    string(REGEX MATCH "return [0-9]+" DUMP_MATCH ${AC_COMPUTER_DUMP})
    string(REGEX REPLACE "return " "" DUMP_MATCH ${DUMP_MATCH})

    set(${OUTPUT_VAR} "${DUMP_MATCH}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()


set(MY_FANCY_INPUT "sizeof(int) * 8 + 1")

AC_COMPUTE_INT(MY_FANCY_OUTPUT ${MY_FANCY_INPUT})
message(STATUS "Expression: ${MY_FANCY_INPUT}")
message(STATUS "Evaluates to: ${MY_FANCY_OUTPUT}"
```

Which brings us the following:

```
$ cmake ../
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Expression: sizeof(int) * 8 + 1
-- Evaluates to: 33
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/c_test/bin
```

EDIT:
as far as I get from `autoconf` source, it does series of compile cycles with possible size values (binary search between lo and hi bounds). Event thought, still not sure how exactly it connects to proper expression execution.

EDIT2:
relevant `autoconf` [commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/autoconf.git/commit/?id=ca1006165900df4707b0caaa0a9378923812cca0) and source of [_AC_COMPUTE_INT](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/autoconf.git/tree/lib/autoconf/general.m4#n3083)

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot upvote this, due it being very unportable. It doesn't even work with clang. Even parsing the value from generated binary files would be more portable than this. In contrast, autotools binary search is quite portable.

Comment: @HelmutGrohne yup. It is very unportable. In progress of porting Autotools binary search. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Maybe we should move the discussion to the CMake issue tracker? I'd really like to see this functionality in CMake upstream. Then, I could simply send patches bumping the minimum CMake version without having to embed this code into tens of CMake projects.

Answer (score 1):

OK, giving it another shot. Dumb bruteforce in the right direction of the value using `_Static_assert()` from C11.  Bruteforce part to be updated to proper binary search.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

# we need this gimmic because math(EXPR ...) does not work well with negative numbers
function (INC OUTPUT_VAR NUMBER)
    if (${NUMBER} LESS 0)
        math(EXPR res_var "0 ${NUMBER} + 1")
    else()
        math(EXPR res_var "${NUMBER} + 1")
    endif()

    set(${OUTPUT_VAR} ${res_var} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

function (DEC OUTPUT_VAR NUMBER)
    if (${NUMBER} LESS 0)
        math(EXPR res_var "0 ${NUMBER} - 1")
    else()
        math(EXPR res_var "${NUMBER} - 1")
    endif()
    set(${OUTPUT_VAR} ${res_var} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

# passing expression through pipe to C compiler instead of file.
# can be done in more portable manner, of course
function(GCC_ASSERT OUTPUT_VAR EXPRESSION)
    execute_process(
        COMMAND bash -c "echo '${EXPRESSION}' | ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -o /dev/null -xc -c -"
        RESULT_VARIABLE result_var
        OUTPUT_QUIET ERROR_QUIET
        )

    if (${result_var} EQUAL 0)
        set(${OUTPUT_VAR} true PARENT_SCOPE)
    else()
        set(${OUTPUT_VAR} false PARENT_SCOPE)
    endif()
endfunction()

function(GCC_IF_LESS OUTPUT_VAR A B)
    set(C_EXPRESSION "_Static_assert(((signed int)${A}) < ((signed int)${B}), \"\")\;")
    GCC_ASSERT(TEST_CON_LESS ${C_EXPRESSION})
    set(${OUTPUT_VAR} ${TEST_CON_LESS} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

function(AC_COMPUTE_INT OUTPUT_VAR EXPRESSION)
    set(MID_POINT 1)
    # if expression evaluates to something < MID_POINT, keep decreasing it
    # if expression evaluates to something > MID_POINT, keep increasing it
    # if it's neither, we have the right MID_POINT which is equal to
    # evaluated expression
    while(true)
        GCC_IF_LESS(EXPRESSION_IS_LESS ${EXPRESSION} ${MID_POINT})
        GCC_IF_LESS(EXPRESSION_IS_MORE ${MID_POINT} ${EXPRESSION})
        if (${EXPRESSION_IS_LESS})
            DEC(MID_POINT ${MID_POINT})
        elseif(${EXPRESSION_IS_MORE})
            INC(MID_POINT ${MID_POINT})
        else()
            set(${OUTPUT_VAR} ${MID_POINT} PARENT_SCOPE)
            break()
        endif()
    endwhile()
endfunction()

set(MY_FANCY_INPUT "sizeof(int) * 8 - 40")

AC_COMPUTE_INT(MY_FANCY_OUTPUT ${MY_FANCY_INPUT})
message(STATUS "Expression: ${MY_FANCY_INPUT}")
message(STATUS "Evaluates to: ${MY_FANCY_OUTPUT}")
```

Example output:

```
-- Expression: sizeof(int) * 8 - 40
-- Evaluates to: -8
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Comment: This is way better than all alternatives presented thus far. Still lacking in a few points: 1. Having projects embed that pile of cmake code is bad. It should be upstream or something. 2. You mentioned binary search. 3. You can remove the requirement on C11 if you use arrays `char x[condition ? 1 : -1];`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware if there is an existing module for this.

However, here is an approach, that you can try to implement yourself. You can use `execute_process` to run `${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -E` on a file containing something like

```
// all #include's you need

xxx(YOUR_DEFINE)xxx
```

This would produce a file with `xxx(<some_int>)xxx` line. Now use CMake's `file(READ` and `string(REGEX` to pull that out.

Comment: Hum, no, `sizeof` won't work. Maybe we should ask OP what he really tries to achieve.

Comment: I was looking into it and it did not appear to evaluate. And most of the examples of `AC_COMPUTE_INT` usage in the wild involves `sizeof` of various native types. Still don't get it how it's actually implemented in `autoconf`. Redefinition of `sizeof` to INT_MIN/INT_MAX/CHAR_MIN/CHAR_MAX/etc?

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't work with `sizeof`. Some projects use a variant of `AC_COMPUTE_INT` to compute stuff that contains `sizeof` (no clue why) and others use it to examine macros from their dependencies. For the latter we cannot make any assumptions on how they are defined besides being compile time constants. Thus we must expect `sizeof` being used.

Comment: Seems so: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xkfswhy.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396